# Anonymous functions syntax in CoffeeScript

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

I've been looking at [CoffeeScript](http://jashkenas.github.com/coffee-script/) and I'm not understanding how you would write code like this. How does it handle nested anonymous functions in its syntax?

```
;(function($) {
          var app = $.sammy(function() {

            this.get('#/', function() {
              $('#main').text('');
            });

            this.get('#/test', function() {
              $('#main').text('Hello World');
            });

          });

          $(function() {
            app.run()
          });
        })(jQuery);
```

Comment: The [CoffeeScript website](http://jashkenas.github.com/coffee-script/) has a *Try CoffeeScript* feature, which compiles to JavaScript on the fly.  I was able to figure out the answer in a few minutes playing around with it.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

didn't actually compile it, but this should work

```
(($) ->
  app = $.sammy ->

    this.get '#/', ->
      $('#main').text '' 

    this.get '#/test', ->
      $('#main').text 'Hello World'

  $(->
    app.run()
  )
)(jQuery);
```

Comment: Since coffeescript automatically wraps code in an anonymous function anyway, you can actually just put `$ = jQuery` at the top of your file and take out the calling of an anonymous function with jQuery as a parameter.

Answer (score 36):

Matt's answer is correct, but here's an alternative method:

In CoffeeScript 1.0 (released a few weeks after this question was posed), a `do` operator was introduced that runs the function that immediately follows it. It's mostly used for capturing variables in loops, since

```
for x in arr
  do (x) ->
    setTimeout (-> console.log x), 50
```

(which passes a reference to `x` into the anonymous function) behaves differently than

```
for x in arr
  setTimeout (-> console.log x), 50
```

The latter will simply output the last entry in `arr` repeatedly, since there's only one `x`.

Anyway, you should be aware of `do` as a way of running an anonymous function without the extra parentheses, though its capabilities with respect to argument-passing are a bit limited at the moment. I've raised a [proposal to broaden them](http://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script/issues/960).

Currently, the equivalent of your code example would be

```
do ->
  $ = jQuery
  ...
```

If my proposal is accepted, it will be possible to write

```
do ($ = jQuery) ->
  ...
```

instead.

Comment: This method is really nice, as accounting for coffeescript philosofy it does not require any closing brackets

Answer (score 5):

Short variant

```
do ($=jQuery)->
 app = $.sammy ->
   @get '#/', -> $("#main").text ''
   @get '#/test', -> $('#main').text 'Hello world'
 $ -> app.run()
```